# Serial allocators/deallocators

Tags: c++, malloc, wrapper, cuda

I have a code that has a large number of `malloc`s and device-specific API mallocs (I'm programming on a GPU, so `cudaMalloc`).

Basically my end of my beginning of my code is a big smorgasbord of allocation calls, while my closing section is deallocation calls.

As I've encapsulated my global data in structures, the deallocations are quite long, but at least I can break them into a separate function.  On the other hand, I would like a shorter solution.  Additionally an automatic deallocator would reduce the risk of memory leaks created if I forget to explicitly write the deallocation in the global allocator function.

I was wondering whether it'd be possible to write some sort of templated class wrapper that can allow me to "register" variables during the `malloc`/`cudaMalloc` process, and then at the end of simulation do a mass loop-based deallocation (deregistration).  To be clear I don't want to type out individual deallocations (`free`/`cudaFree`s), because again this is long and undesirable, and the assumption would be that anything I register won't be deallocated until the device simulation is complete and main is terminating.

A benefit here is that if I register a new simulation duration variable, it will automatically deallocate, so there's no danger of me forgetting do deallocate it and creating a memory leak.

Is such a wrapper possible?

Would you suggest doing it?

If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Old problem, but CUDA gives a new flavor to it. Interesting.

Comment: Are you amenable to C++ answers or was your "C" tag intentional?

Comment: It should be C++.  Originally the project was in C, but I added some STL stuff on the host end as it offers cleaner easier printing control in my mind.  The device code and allocation/deallocation is all traditional C though, there's no classes @ present.

Comment: Since you use STL, you might find Thrust helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An idea:

Create both functions, one that allocates memory and provides valid pointers after register them in a "list" of allocated pointers. In the second method, loop this list and deallocate all pointers:

```
// ask for new allocated pointer that will be registered automatically in list of pointers.
pointer1 = allocatePointer(size, listOfPointers);
pointer2 = allocatePointer(size, listOfPointers);

...
// deallocate all pointers
deallocatePointers(listOfPointers);
```

Even, you may use different `listOfPointers` depending of your simulation scope:

```
listOfPointer1 = getNewListOfPointers();
listOfPointer2 = getNewListOfPointers();
....
p1 = allocatePointer(size, listOfPointer1);
p2 = allocatePointer(size, listOfPointer2);
...
deallocatePointers(listOfPointers1);
...
deallocatePointers(listOfPointers2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to skin a cat, as they say.

I would recommend thrust's [device_vector](http://code.google.com/p/thrust/wiki/QuickStartGuide#Vectors) as a memory management tool.  It abstracts allocation, deallocation, and memcpy in CUDA.  It also gives you access to all the algorithms that Thrust provides.

I wouldn't recommend keeping random lists of unrelated pointers as Tio Pepe recommends.  Instead you should encapsulate related data into a class.  Even if you use `thrust::device_vector` you may want to encapsulate multiple related vectors and operations on them into a class.

Comment: But that is C++? edit: I see now that CUDA supports C++, but it didn't originally. Anyway, the question is about C, but that could an oversight of OP of course.

Comment: CUDA is C++.  It has always supported parts of C++ (such as templates), and has gradually been adding more complete support.  I don't see anything in the question that limits it to C.

Comment: maybe, but Wikipedia anyway says "CUDA (with compute capability 1.x) uses a recursion-free, function-pointer-free subset of the C language, plus some simple extensions. "  Maybe those simple extensions were templates I don't know. The question is tagged "C", but as I said, that might be an oversight on the part of OP.

Comment: Wikipedia is not accurate in this instance.  And this is not relevant, since the OP only wants to know about handling host-side code (cudaMalloc is a host-side function), where any C++ is valid (assuming host compiler supports it).

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is probably to use the smart pointers from C++ boost library, if that is an option.

If not, the best you can hope for in C is a program design that allows you to write allocation and deallocation in one place. Perhaps something like the following pseudo code:

```
while(!terminate_program)
{
  switch(state_machine)
  {
    case STATE_PREOPERATIONAL:
      myclass_init(); // only necessary for non-global/static objects
      myclass_mem_manager();
      state_machine = STATE_RUNNING;
    break;

    case STATE_RUNNING:
      myclass_do_stuff();
      ...
    break;

    ...

    case STATE_EXIT:
      myclass_mem_manager();
      terminate_program = true;
    break;
  }


void myclass_init()
{
  ptr_x = NULL; 
  ptr_y = NULL;

  /* Where ptr_x, ptr_y are some of the many objects to allocate/deallocate.
     If ptr is a global/static, (static storage duration) it is 
     already set to NULL automatically and this function isn't 
     necessary */
}

void myclass_mem_manager()
{
  ptr_x = mem_manage (ptr_x, items_x*sizeof(Type_x));
  ptr_y = mem_manage (ptr_y, items_y*sizeof(Type_y));
}


static void* mem_manage (const void* ptr, size_t bytes_n)
{
  if(ptr == NULL)
  {
    ptr = malloc(bytes_n);

    if (ptr == NULL)
    {} // error handling
  }
  else
  {
    free(ptr);
    ptr = NULL;
  }

  return ptr;
}
```